# How Can I Track Geolocation Using Cordova/PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have tried to use [org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1299) to track geolocation in the background, but it is buggy, and has battery issues. What methods I can use to track geolocation in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the PhoneGap documentation? They have [several methods](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) for geolocation ([`getCurrentPosition`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition), [`watchPosition`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition), and [`clearWatch`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.clearWatch)).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594483/phonegap-geolocation-track-position-if-app-closed) might help, but none of the answers are accepted or up voted.

---

I also came across [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) that you might want to look into.

**Instillation**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation.git
```

**Use**

The plugin creates the object `window.BackgroundGeolocation`. See [API Documentation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/blob/master/docs/api.md) for details